# Vector drawable throws Resources$NotFoundException caused by long pathData

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have few vector drawables in my android project but I have a particulary problem with one of them.

My application crashes when It tries to show up that vector drawable. It is built from multiple `path` attributes, however, after deleting every `path` and starting to add one by one I observed that the crash is caused by a very long `pathData`.

The `pathData` cannot be split into multiple paths so my question is, is there any other solution for this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: how long is it? whats the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem, I will post it as an answer to help anyone facing the same problem.

So if you get Resource not found exception but you still have the resource, the problem is with your path data that is too long. Mine had 46 000 characters.

The only solution I found was to split this pathData into two paths.

Comment: may i know how can i split the path data into two? need any tools to help?

Comment: You do not need any tools, it's pretty straightforward how you can do it. Look carefully